# HTML Email is seen as text email despite setting headers

Tags: php, html, email

I've looked at the documentation and here's how I'm sending my email:

```
$headers = 'From: aaaaaa@aaa.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: aaaa@aaa.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Send
mail('aaaaa'aaaa.com', 'Contact: ' . $name . ' from ' .$company, $message, $header);
```

Where `$message` is a string containing several `<br />` tags for line breaks.

I've set the `Content-type` to `text/html` so I would expect the email to arrive as HTML, but in my inbox it's clearly interpreted as just text (IE: I just see the text of my `<br />` tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this

```
$headers = 'From: email@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       ^ - notice the s?

$company, $message, $header )
                           ^ missing the s
```

Comment: @Juicy I understand; I've been there too. You're very much welcome.